# Testing if a pointer is to a file or a buffer

Tags: c

I have two Variadic functions in a C program, one to close one or more files, and another to free one or more buffers. The version for closing files is as follows:

```
int closeFiles(int n, ...) {
  FILE** fp;
  va_list ptr;
  va_start(ptr, n);
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    fp = va_arg(ptr, FILE**);
    if (*fp == NULL) continue;
    fclose(*fp);
    *fp = NULL;
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

and the version for freeing buffers is as follows:

```
int freeBuffers(int n, ...) {
  BYTE** bp;
  va_list ptr;
  va_start(ptr, n);
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    bp = va_arg(ptr, BYTE**);
    if (*bp == NULL) continue;
    free(*bp);
    *bp = NULL;
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

In the header is the `#include <stdarg.h>` statement. I've included a counter in both functions. The first function is called as `closeFiles(3, &fp1, &fp2, &fp3);` in this case for 3 files, and likewise `freeBuffer(3, &bp1, &bp2, &bp3);` for 3 buffers. The functions are very similar, and I would like to combine them into a single function where I can specify zero or more files to close, and/or zero or more buffers to free. To do this I need to know if a pointer is to a file or to a buffer, but I can't find any documentation that enables one to find this out. Perhaps someone can advise me to solve this.

Comment: C and C++ are two very different languages, please don't tag both unless your question is actually related to both languages (like a comparison or similar). The code you show is plain C, something which you state yourself in the first sentence of your question. Please don't tag multiple unrelated languages in the future.

Comment: As for your question, unless you specify some format like `printf` or `scanf` then the answer is no, you can not combine the functions. There's no way to know the actual type of the argument in a varargs function. You could use some macros to write most of the code once, but you still need two different functions.

Comment: Possibly `CloseFilesAndFreeBuffers(int fileCount, int bufferCount, ...)`?

Comment: @csharp, Use `freeBuffers(n, G(&fp1), G(&bp2), G(&bp3))` where `G()` is a macro `#define G(p) H(p), p` and `H()` uses `_Generic` to translate a pointer type to an index.  Then `freeBuffers()` get 2 parameters for each:, an index type and the pointer.

Comment: Just add another parameter (before the `n` parameter) that indicates whether the pointers are files or buffers. Then, in the body of the function, all you need is an `if` statement that chooses between `fclose` and `free`.

Comment: @csharo Now you have been presented with some possible workarounds. All that would, quite honestly, make your code worse and less maintainable. So please [edit] your question to tell us the *reason* you want to combine the two functions? What is the actual and underlying problem that's supposed to solve? If you don't really have an answer to that, then I suggest you leave the functions alone.

Comment: You could make a struct (or union) called `FileOrBuffer` and use that everywhere.  One member is an integer indicating the type, and then another member is a `void *` pointing to the underlying object.  Then you'd be able to write code that can use it (and free it) without caring what the underlying type is.  That would introduce some overhead of course so I wouldn't do it unless it's really necessary.

Comment: It sounds like [XY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) probem

Comment: As for figuring out whether a pointer points to a file or a buffer, that can't be done if the only information you have is the pointer itself. That's because a file pointer *is* a pointer to a buffer. Specifically, a `FILE *` points to a buffer that contains a `FILE` struct. Part of `fclose` is to `free` that buffer.

Comment: You could add a `void dispose(void * p)` parameter that you apply to each va arg. Call your function with `free` for buffers, and `fclose` for `FILE`s. Downside is you don't get the return code from calling `fclose()`, which you really should be checking even if to just log / report errors.

Comment: How would this code handle failures on `fclose()`? `fclose()` can fail just like `fwrite()` or `fprintf()` can - if you want to reliably handle failures in ways that don't cause silent loss of data, you have to handle errors from `fclose()` too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid your efforts are misdirected: your vararg functions to close streams or free buffers are fragile and inefficient:

- *fragile* because the compiler cannot typecheck the arguments, so you might inadvertently pass the wrong type or the wrong count
- *inefficient* because these wrappers involve extra code that is not cheap on some architectures for very little benefits.

Furthermore, there is no portable way to determine the actual type of these functions' arguments, so combining them is a recipe for failure.  There might be some contorted way to combine macros and `_Generic` expressions to achieve a partial solution, but please do not even try.

You could define a `closeFile` inline function to call `fclose` if the `FILE*` is not a null pointer, and even pass pointers to ensure the `FILE*` is set to null after closing:

```
static inline void closeFile(FILE **fpp) {
    if (*fpp) {
        fclose(*fpp);
        *fpp = NULL;
    }
}
```

But the vararg generalisation seems overkill.

For allocated arrays, the same approach is tricky because `void **` is not compatible with `char **`, so the function would a cast on its argument or be restricted to a specific type.  For a generic solution in C23, you could use the `typeof()` pseudo operator to define an intermediary variable so any side effects in `pp` only occur once:

```
// using typeof(**(pp)) to try and ensure freeBuffer is invoked with a pointer address.
#define freeBuffer(pp) \
    do { \
       typeof(**(pp)) **pp__ = pp; free(*pp__); *pp__ = 0; \
    } while (0)
```

Answer (score 1):

> To do this I need to know if a pointer is to a file or to a buffer, but I can't find any documentation that enables one to find this out.

C does not specify that a pointer's value contains type information.  Yet the code calling `freeBuffers( p1, p2, p3, ...)` does know if `p...` is a `FILE *` or `char *`.

To meet your goal code needs to either:

- Pass additional information to `freeBuffers()` besides only `n` and the pointers.
- Steer code to call other `freeBuffers()`-like functions (function overloading), if `n` is not too high.

Both are possible in C with macros and `_Generic`.

**Should you do this?**

Unless you have a compelling need or evidence this simplifies overall code, don't.

```
//  Consider this
free_file(&fp1);
free_buffer(&bp2);
free_buffer(&bp3);

// Instead of 
freeBuffers(3, &fp1, &bp2, &bp3);
```

Comment: `fclose(fp1);` would have undefined behavior if `fp1` is null, which is supported by `freeBuffers()`.

Comment: @chqrlie Good point.  Suggestion in answer improved.

Comment: Many thanks for all the suggestions. I also tried combining the two functions in the form "(int freeClose(int m, int n, ...)" where I iterate over m buffers, then n files, but that doesn't work either. So it looks as if the easiest is to keep the buffers and files in separate functions.